# Trying to toggle UV editor area?

Tags: python, scripting

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D': 
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
        bpy.ops.screen.area_split(override, direction='VERTICAL', factor=0.3,)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you are trying to change the VIEW3D area of the current screen to UV Editor and split it. Here is the changed code snippet

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D': 
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
        area.ui_type = 'UV'
        bpy.ops.screen.area_split(override, direction='VERTICAL', factor=0.3,)
```

Comment: and possibly have this button toggle to close the new UV editor window?